# Differentiability and scalar product

Tags: real-analysis

I have some problems trying to prove this exercise.

$f : U \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is diferenciable on the open $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}.$ Assume that $df(a)\neq 0$ at an  $a \in U.$ Prove that exist a unit vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $df(a)(u) = \max\{df(a)(h) : \lVert h\rVert= 1\}.$ if $v \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ satisfies $df(a)(v) = 0,$ then $<v,u>=0$ (u and v are perpendicular).

I know that $\{h\in \mathbb{R}^{m} : \lVert h\rVert= 1\}$ is a compact set $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $df(a)$ is continuos, hence $\max\{df(a)(h) : \lVert h\rVert= 1\}$ exist. that is all I have. I do not have any idea how to prove $<v,u>=0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Presumably you have a (simple) formula for $u$ in terms of $df(a)$. Fix a vector $v$. If we define $g(t) = f(a + tv)$, the chain rule gives
$$
g'(0) = df(a)(v) = [df(a)]^{t} \cdot v.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not seeing how I can get <v,u>=0.

Comment: If you have a formula for $u$ in terms of $df(a)$, then $df(a)(v) = 0$ if and only if $\langle u, v\rangle = 0$ should be almost obvious; do you have a formula for $u$ in terms of $df(a)$?

Comment: I know that $df(a)(u)=<Vf(a),u>=\lVert Vf(a) \rVert$ since $df(a)(u) = \max\{df(a)(h) : \lVert h\rVert= 1\} .$

Comment: Almost there: $u$ is the unique positive scalar multiple of the gradient vector $df(a)^{t}$ that has unit length.